# Show that $f$ is a bounded function if $f(x)+f''(x)=-xg(x)f'(x)$ where $g\ge0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a twice differentiable real valued function such that 
$f(x)+f''(x)=-xg(x)f'(x)$
Where $g(x)\geq 0$ for all real $x$
Show that $|f(x) |$ is a bounded function.

Comment: Even though the problem is false, perhaps it is worth mentioning that $(f(x)+f''(x))f'(x)=-g(x)f'(x)^2<=0$ which means $f(x)^2+f'(x)^2$ is a decreasing function. So $f$ is bounded in $[x,\infty)$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I've edited the question

Answer (score 4):

FALSE.

Take $f (x)=e^{-x} $.

then

$$f (x)+f''(x)=2e^{-x}=-g (x)f'(x) $$

with $g (x)=2$.

but $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}f (x)=+\infty . $$

Comment: I've  edited the question.